# Как написать алгоритм для записи истории вычислений, а также просто для получения результата цепочки вычислений в упрощённом калькуляторе?

Tags: c#, winforms, калькулятор

Писал калькулятор на с#. И всё бы ничего, но по условию задачи нужно вести "историю" вычислений в отдельном ListBox. Он должен находиться сбоку. А в TextBox нужно выводить не историю, а нечто другое. ВОЗМОЖНО просто вычисления. Но вот что конкретно-я не очень понимаю. Возможно, что Вам, читающему/ей мои запутанные объяснения больше помогут те комментарии по ней, которые мне удалось раздобыть.Собственно в них по идее содержится вся нужная информация для решения и написания искомого мной алгоритма, но я не понимаю как эту задачу осуществить Привожу их (комментарии) ниже:

**Комментарий №1**
Калькулятор предназначен для выполнения ЦЕПОЧКИ действий:

(((3+5) -7)+1)...= .

Скобки всегда группируются влево, поэтому пользователь вводит данные так:

```
     3

   + 5

   - 7

   + 1 

   ...

   =
```

В t0.Text пишутся только числа, а знаки операций -- запоминаются в переменной op. Все вместе, т.е. протокол, записывается в отдельном ListBox. Имеем 3 переменных:

float a (регистр), float b (правый операнд) и char op (знак операции или символ 'N' в самом начале).

1) *Начало.* op='N' и пользователь набирает первое число цифровыми кнопками. Когда набор закончится и будет нажата одна из кнопок со знаками операций, то набранное число перемещается в a, т.е. a=float.Parse(t0.Text)); t0.Clear(); , а в op запоминается операция (напр., op='+').

2) *Продолжение.* Пользователь кнопками набирает правый операнд (напр., второе слагаемое) и жмет кнопку со следующей операцией (напр., '-'). Тогда b=float.Parse(t0.Text)); t0.Clear(); и выполняется предыдущая операция (которая сохранена в op) между a и b (напр., a= a+b). После этого в op запоминается операция с нажатой кнопки (в примере '-'). Она будет выполнена на следующем такте работы по пункту 2. Пересчитанное значение a НЕ выводится в t0.Text, это поле только ДЛЯ ВВОДА И КОНЕЧНОГО РЕЗУЛЬТАТА. Такты работы (пункт 2) повторяются, пока не будет нажата кнопка '='.

3) *Завершение.* Пользователь кнопками набирает очередной правый операнд и нажимает кнопку '='. Тогда выполняется все то, что было в пункте 2, но еще выводится в t0.Text подсчитанное значение a  и в переменную op помещается 'N'.

Это описание алгоритма без протоколирования, которое нужно сделать в отдельном ListBox. Туда на каждом такте работы записывается, что сделано.

**Комментарий №2**

После того, как определённая последовательность действий закончилась, её результат был получен и выведен в протоколе (истории) нажатием кнопки "=" (т.е. там появилась запись вида "= 55" ), дальнейшие действия проводятся именно с 55. Но чистить протокол  в этот момент нет необходимости. Например:

```
  1

  +

  10

  * 

  5

  = 55

  +

  5

  -

  50

  = 10
```

Для очистки всего и, в частности, протокола у калькулятора есть специальная кнопочка Clear, которая должна приводить его в исходное состояние.

**Так, теперь я привожу ту часть кода, которая уже есть. В общем, задача состоит в том, чтобы в неё встроить этот верный алгоритм для протокола в ListBox, а также понять по комментариям выше, что всё-таки нужно в TextBox тогда.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace zadacha
{
    class Form1 : Form
    {
    TextBox t0 = new TextBox();
    ListBox l0 = new ListBox();
    Button b0 = new Button();
    Button b1 = new Button();
    Button b2 = new Button();
    Button b3 = new Button();
    Button b4 = new Button();
    Button b5 = new Button();
    Button b6 = new Button();
    Button b7 = new Button();
    Button b8 = new Button();
    Button b9 = new Button();
    Button b10 = new Button();
    Button b11 = new Button();
    Button b12 = new Button();
    Button b13 = new Button();
    Button b14 = new Button();
    Button b15 = new Button();
    Button b16 = new Button();
    Button b17 = new Button();

    public Form1()
    {
        this.Size = new Size(550, 550);
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

        //ТЕКСТБОКС
        t0.Location = new Point(10, 20);
        t0.Size = new Size(350, 200);
        t0.Font = new Font(t0.Font.FontFamily, 24);
        this.Controls.Add(t0);

        //ЛИСТБОКС!!!!!
        l0.Size = new Size(150, 500);
        l0.Location = new Point(375, 10);
        this.Controls.Add(l0);

        //КНОПКИ
        //ЦИФОРВЫЕ КНОПКИ
        // 1 СТРОКА
        b0.Location = new Point(10, t0.Top + 60);
        b0.Size = new Size(95, 50);
        b0.Text = "7";
        b0.Click += new EventHandler(b0_Click);
        b0.Font = new Font(b0.Font.FontFamily, 16);
        this.Controls.Add(b0);
        b1.Location = new Point(b0.Top + b0.Height + 7, t0.Top + 60);
        b1.Size = new Size(95, 50);
        b1.Text = "8";
        b1.Click += new EventHandler(b1_Click);
        b1.Font = new Font(b1.Font.FontFamily, 16);
        this.Controls.Add(b1);
        b2.Location = new Point(263, t0.Top + 60);
        b2.Size = new Size(95, 50);
        b2.Text = "9";
        b2.Click += new EventHandler(b2_Click);
        b2.Font = new Font(b2.Font.FontFamily, 16);
        this.Controls.Add(b2);
        // 2 СТРОКА
        b3.Location = new Point(10, b0.Top + 75);
        b3.Size = new Size(95, 50);
        b3.Text = "4";
        b3.Click += new EventHandler(b3_Click);
        b3.Font = new Font(b3.Font.FontFamily, 16);
        this.Controls.Add(b3);
        b4.Location = new Point(b3.Left + b3.Width + 32, b0.Top + 75);
        b4.Size = new Size(95, 50);
        b4.Text = "5";
        b4.Click += new EventHandler(b4_Click);
        b4.Font = new Font(b4.Font.FontFamily, 16);
        this.Controls.Add(b4);
        b5.Location = new Point(b4.Left + b4.Width + 32, b0.Top + 75);
        b5.Size = new Size(95, 50);
        b5.Text = "6";
        b5.Click += new EventHandler(b5_Click);
        b5.Font = new Font(b5.Font.FontFamily, 16);
        this.Controls.Add(b5);
        // 3 СТРОКА
        b6.Location = new Point(10, b3.Top + 75);
        b6.Size = new Size(95, 50);
        b6.Text = "1";
        b6.Click += new EventHandler(b6_Click);
        b6.Font = new Font(b6.Font.FontFamily, 16);
        this.Controls.Add(b6);
        b7.Location = new Point(b6.Left + b6.Width + 32, b3.Top + 75);
        b7.Size = new Size(95, 50);
        b7.Text = "2";
        b7.Click += new EventHandler(b7_Click);
        b7.Font = new Font(b7.Font.FontFamily, 16);
        this.Controls.Add(b7);
        b8.Location = new Point(b7.Left + b7.Width + 32, b3.Top + 75);
        b8.Size = new Size(95, 50);
        b8.Text = "3";
        b8.Click += new EventHandler(b8_Click);
        b8.Font = new Font(b8.Font.FontFamily, 16);
        this.Controls.Add(b8);
        // 4 СТРОКА
        b9.Location = new Point(b6.Left + b6.Width + 32, b6.Top + 75);
        b9.Size = new Size(95, 50);
        b9.Text = "0";
        b9.Click += new EventHandler(b9_Click);
        b9.Font = new Font(b9.Font.FontFamily, 16);
        this.Controls.Add(b9);

        b15.Location = new Point(10, b6.Top + 75);
        b15.Size = new Size(95, 50);
        b15.Text = ",";
        b15.Click += new EventHandler(b15_Click);
        b15.Font = new Font(b15.Font.FontFamily, 16);
        this.Controls.Add(b15);
        b16.Location = new Point(10, b9.Top + 150);
        b16.Size = new Size(95, 50);
        b16.Text = "C";
        b16.Click += new EventHandler(b16_Click);
        b16.Font = new Font(b16.Font.FontFamily, 16);
        this.Controls.Add(b16);
        //КНОПКИ С ВЫЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНЫМИ ОПЕРАЦИЯМИ ВНЕШНОСТЬ
        b10.Location = new Point(10, b9.Top + 75);
        b10.Size = new Size(95, 50);
        b10.Text = "+";
        b10.Click += new EventHandler(b10_Click);
        b10.Font = new Font(b10.Font.FontFamily, 16);
        this.Controls.Add(b10);

        b11.Location = new Point(b10.Left + b10.Width + 32, b9.Top + 75);
        b11.Size = new Size(95, 50);
        b11.Text = "x";
        b11.Click += new EventHandler(b11_Click);
        b11.Font = new Font(b11.Font.FontFamily, 16);
        this.Controls.Add(b11);

        b12.Location = new Point(b11.Left + b11.Width + 32, b9.Top + 75);
        b12.Size = new Size(95, 50);
        b12.Text = "-";
        b12.Click += new EventHandler(b12_Click);
        b12.Font = new Font(b12.Font.FontFamily, 16);
        this.Controls.Add(b12);

        b13.Location = new Point(b10.Left + b10.Width + 32, b10.Top + 75);
        b13.Size = new Size(95, 50);
        b13.Text = "/";
        b13.Click += new EventHandler(b13_Click);
        b13.Font = new Font(b13.Font.FontFamily, 16);
        this.Controls.Add(b13);

        b14.Location = new Point(b7.Left + b7.Width + 32, b6.Top + 75);
        b14.Size = new Size(95, 50);
        b14.Text = "=";
        b14.Click += new EventHandler(b14_Click);
        b14.Font = new Font(b14.Font.FontFamily, 16);
        this.Controls.Add(b14);
    }


/*  float a, b;
    int count;
    bool znak = true;  */


    //1 СТРОКА
    private void b0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t0.Text = t0.Text + "7";
    }
    private void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t0.Text = t0.Text + "8";
    }
    private void b2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t0.Text = t0.Text + "9";
    }
    //2 СТРОКА
    private void b3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t0.Text = t0.Text + "4";
    }
    private void b4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t0.Text = t0.Text + "5";
    }
    private void b5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t0.Text = t0.Text + "6";
    }
    //3 СТРОКА
    private void b6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t0.Text = t0.Text + "1";
    }
    private void b7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t0.Text = t0.Text + "2";
    }
    private void b8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t0.Text = t0.Text + "3";
    }
    //4 СТРОКА
    private void b9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t0.Text = t0.Text + "0";
    }
    private void b15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t0.Text = t0.Text + ",";
    }

    private void b16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t0.Text = "";
    }

    //функция для подсчёта (старая и видимо неверная)
    /*        private void calculate()
           {
               switch (count)
               {
                   case 1:
                       b = a + float.Parse(t0.Text);
                       t0.Text = b.ToString();
                       break;
                   case 2:
                       b = a - float.Parse(t0.Text);
                       t0.Text = b.ToString();
                       break;
                   case 3:
                       b = a * float.Parse(t0.Text);
                       t0.Text = b.ToString();
                       break;
                   case 4:
                       b = a / float.Parse(t0.Text);
                       t0.Text = b.ToString();
                       break;
                   default:
                       break;
               }
           }

   */

   //ФУНКЦИЯ ДЛЯ ПРОТОКОЛА ЛИСТБОКСА  (пока просто почти копия функции выше, ничего не изменено почти)


    float a, b;
    char op = 'N';

    int count;
    bool znak = true;

    private void calculate()
    {
        switch (count)
        {
            case 1:
                a = float.Parse(t0.Text);
                t0.Clear();
                op = '+';
                b = float.Parse(t0.Text);
                t0.Clear();

                break;

            case 2:
                a = float.Parse(t0.Text);
                t0.Clear();
                op = '*';
                break;

            case 3:
                a = float.Parse(t0.Text);
                t0.Clear();
                op = '-';
                break;

            case 4:
                a = float.Parse(t0.Text);
                t0.Clear();
                op = '/';
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }








    //ПОСЛЕ Ф-ЦИИ ОБРАБОТЧИКИ КНОПОК С ВЫЧ. ОПЕРАЦИЯМИ
    private void b10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a = float.Parse(t0.Text);
        t0.Clear();
        count = 1;
        t0.Text = a.ToString() + "+";
        znak = true;
    }
    private void b11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a = float.Parse(t0.Text);
        t0.Clear();
        count = 2;
        t0.Text = a.ToString() + "x";
        znak = true;
    }
    private void b12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a = float.Parse(t0.Text);
        t0.Clear();
        count = 3;
        t0.Text = a.ToString() + "-";
        znak = true;
    }
    private void b13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a = float.Parse(t0.Text);
        t0.Clear();
        count = 4;
        t0.Text = a.ToString() + "/";
        znak = true;
    }

    private void b14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  calculate();  пока убрал её подальше
        t0.Text = "";
    }





    }
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Form1 f = new Form1();
            Application.Run(f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Текста много, кода много, но не понятно, в чем у вас конкретно вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос в том, как добавить (и написать его, потому что у меня пока не получилось) сам этот алгоритм (который для истории вычислений в ListBox) в код, и что в таком случае должно быть в TextBox.

Comment: В общем не получается сам калькулятор, в коде есть пока только кнопки, текстбокс и листбокс и какие-то попытки написать алгоритм

Comment: Что должно быть в `TextBox` и что должно быть в `ListBox` - это ведь относится к постановке задачи, верно? Мы не можем знать, что именно имел ввиду тот, кто ставил вам задачу. Вам надо это у автора задачи уточнять.

Comment: Ну, всё-таки, то, что должно быть в ListBox есть в двух комментариях, которые я привёл видимо, (и это должно именно в столбик выводиться как в примерах, поэтому мой ListBox в коде имеет такой вид), но у меня сам алгоритм, который описан в комментариях реализовать не получилось пока. Это главная проблема. Потом уже надо понять что в TextBox, потому что там вроде проще, и возможно всё нужное есть в комментариях, но я, честно говоря, не понял, что требуется. Может Ваш опыт позволит Вам понять? У меня не получилось пока..

Comment: Если это не только мне неясно, но и Вам, то я постараюсь ещё узнать что-то..

Comment: Ну, то есть по сути все объяснения по решению есть в комментариях, которые я привёл, но я не понял, как ими воспользоваться. Я, к сожалению, пока что новичок..

Comment: Подсказать решение я вам не могу пока, потому просто посоветую, как улучшить вопрос - может это привлечет больше людей. Я понимаю, что вы варитесь со своей задачей день или больше, но я, например, трачу минуту на чтение вопроса и я не буду вникать в детали, которые вопроса не касются. Я бы хотел прочитать вопрос и сразу понять, в чем у вас прблема, без чтения простыни кода и ненужных деталей. Ознакомьтесь с инструкцией [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Подправил немного всё, так по идее должно быть лучше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: пример работы]

Создадим класс модели калькулятора

```
public class Calculator : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //INPC
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    //выводная строка
    private string _Output;
    public string Output
    {
        get => _Output;
        set
        {
            _Output = value;
            //оповещаем об изменении значения
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Output)));
        }
    }
    //протокол (коллекция с оповещением об изменении своего состава)
    public BindingList<string> Logs { get; private set; } = new BindingList<string>();
    //регистр
    public float Register { get; private set; }
    //правый операнд
    public float Operand { get; private set; }
    //операция
    public char Operation { get; private set; } = 'N';

    //--Цифры
    public void Zero() => Output += 0;
    public void One() => Output += 1;
    public void Two() => Output += 2;
    public void Three() => Output += 3;
    public void Four() => Output += 4;
    public void Five() => Output += 5;
    public void Six() => Output += 6;
    public void Seven() => Output += 7;
    public void Eight() => Output += 8;
    public void Nine() => Output += 9;

    //Запятая
    public void DecimalPoint()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Output) || Output.Contains(',')) return;

        Output += ',';
    }

    //--Операции
    //сложение
    public void Addition()
    {
        //проверяем ввод
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Output)) return;

        //присваиваем регистру или вычисляем
        MakeOperation();
        //назначаем операцию
        Operation = '+';
        //очищаем вывод
        Output = String.Empty;
    }

    //вычитание
    public void Subtraction()
    {
        //проверяем ввод
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Output)) return;

        //присваиваем регистру или вычисляем
        MakeOperation();
        //назначаем операцию
        Operation = '-';
        //очищаем вывод
        Output = String.Empty;
    }

    //Знак =
    public void EqualSign()
    {
        //проверяем ввод
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Output)) return;

        //вычисляем
        Сalculate();

        //обнуляем операцию
        Operation = 'N';
        //выводим результат
        Output = Register.ToString();
    }

    //очистка
    public void Clear()
    {
        Register = 0.0f;
        Operand = 0.0f;
        Operation = 'N';
        Output = String.Empty;
        Logs.Clear();
    }

    //проведение операции присвоения регистру или запуск вычисления
    private void MakeOperation()
    {
        if (Operation == 'N')
        {
            Register = float.Parse(Output);
            //в протокол
            Logs.Add(Register.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            Сalculate();
        }
    }

    //вычисление предыдущей операции
    private void Сalculate()
    {
        //получаем правый операнд
        Operand = float.Parse(Output);
        //в протокол
        Logs.Add($"{Operation} {Operand}");

        //проводим нужную операцию
        switch (Operation)
        {
            case '+':
                Register += Operand;
                break;
            case '-':
                Register -= Operand;
                break;
            default:
                Debug.WriteLine($"Попытка выполнения ошибочной операции {Operation}");
                Output = String.Empty;
                break;
        }

        //в протокол
        Logs.Add($"= {Register}");
    }
}
```

Проверим его работу на парочке тестов

```
public class CalculatorTests
{
    private Calculator _calculator;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialization()
    {
        _calculator = new Calculator();
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void OneOperation()
    {
        _calculator.One();
        _calculator.Addition();
        _calculator.Two();
        _calculator.EqualSign();

        Assert.AreEqual("3", _calculator.Output);
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void TwoOperations()
    {
        _calculator.One();
        _calculator.Addition();
        _calculator.One();
        _calculator.Subtraction();
        _calculator.One();
        _calculator.EqualSign();

        Assert.AreEqual("1", _calculator.Output);
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void OneOperationAfterAnotherOne()
    {
        _calculator.One();
        _calculator.Addition();
        _calculator.Two();
        _calculator.EqualSign();

        _calculator.Subtraction();
        _calculator.Three();
        _calculator.EqualSign();

        Assert.AreEqual("0", _calculator.Output);
    }
}
```

Теперь присоединим этот класс к визуальному интерфейсу так

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Calculator _calculator;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Типа вычислитель";

        //инициализируем
        _calculator = new Calculator();

        //устанавливаем привязки
        SetBindings();

        //события на нажатия цифровых кнопок
        _button0.Click += ButtonDigit_Click;
        _button1.Click += ButtonDigit_Click;
        _button2.Click += ButtonDigit_Click;
        _button3.Click += ButtonDigit_Click;
        _button4.Click += ButtonDigit_Click;
        _button5.Click += ButtonDigit_Click;
        _button6.Click += ButtonDigit_Click;
        _button7.Click += ButtonDigit_Click;
        _button8.Click += ButtonDigit_Click;
        _button9.Click += ButtonDigit_Click;
        //события на нажатия остальных кнопок
        _buttonClear.Click += Button_Click;
        _buttonPoint.Click += Button_Click;
        _buttonPlus.Click += Button_Click;
        _buttonMinus.Click += Button_Click;
        _buttonEqual.Click += Button_Click;

        _buttonBackspace.Click += ButtonBackspace_Click;
    }

    //установка привязок
    private void SetBindings()
    {
        _textBoxOutput.DataBindings.Add("Text", _calculator, nameof(_calculator.Output));
        _listBoxLog.DataSource = _calculator.Logs;
    }

    private void ButtonDigit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;

        switch (button.Text)
        {
            case "0":
                _calculator.Zero();
                break;
            case "1":
                _calculator.One();
                break;
            case "2":
                _calculator.Two();
                break;
            case "3":
                _calculator.Three();
                break;
            case "4":
                _calculator.Four();
                break;
            case "5":
                _calculator.Five();
                break;
            case "6":
                _calculator.Six();
                break;
            case "7":
                _calculator.Seven();
                break;
            case "8":
                _calculator.Eight();
                break;
            case "9":
                _calculator.Nine();
                break;
            default:
                Debug.WriteLine("Неправильный вызов на цифровой кнопке!");
                break;
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;

        switch (button.Text)
        {
            case "C":
                _calculator.Clear();
                break;
            case ",":
                _calculator.DecimalPoint();
                break;
            case "+":
                _calculator.Addition();
                break;
            case "-":
                _calculator.Subtraction();
                break;
            case "=":
                _calculator.EqualSign();
                break;
            default:
                Debug.WriteLine("Неправильный вызов на нецифровой кнопке!");
                break;
        }
    }

    private void ButtonBackspace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_calculator.Output)) return;

        _calculator.Output = _calculator.Output.Remove(_calculator.Output.Length - 1);
    }
}
```

Весь пример можно посмотреть [здесь](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples/tree/master/CalcWinForms).